# How to get Multiple record(s) from database using MemberID

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

By using below code i am only getting single record from database, but i want to get all the record(s) stored in database for a particular member using MemberID.

For an example, like i have 2 record(s) in my database for the MemberID 1, but whenever i am trying to fetch the record(s) from database getting only first record not both the records, why?

```
<?php
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("mydatabase");

$strMemberID = $_POST["sMemberID"];
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE MemberID = '".$strMemberID."' ";

$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
$obResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($objQuery);

if($obResult)
{
$arr = array();
$arr["OrderID"] = $obResult["OrderID"];
$arr["ItemDetails"] = $obResult["ItemDetails"];
}
mysql_close($objConnect);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: I wonder that people still use mysql_* functions even if they has been deprecated long time ago.

Comment: `$obResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($objQuery);` fetches the first row. You have to run it through a for or a while loop.

Comment: @rkosegi because most of the tutorials and HowTos from the old times still are out there. Is there a standard-SO wo which one should link for injection and for mysqli_ ?

Answer (score 1):

For multiple rows, you need a loop so that you can call `mysql_fetch_assoc()` repeatedly until all rows have been processed:

```
$arr = array();
while($obResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($objQuery))
{
    $arr[] = $obResult;
}
```

Side note: `mysql_*` is deprecated and discouraged, consider upgrading to PDO or MySQLi.

If you must use this old library then remember to wrap `$strMemberID` in `mysql_real_escape_string()` to avoid an SQL Injection hole.

The full code:

```
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("mydatabase");

$strMemberID = $_POST["sMemberID"];
$strSQL = "SELECT OrderID, ItemDetails FROM order_details WHERE MemberID = '".mysql_real_escape_string($strMemberID)."' ";

$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);

$arr = array();
while($obResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($objQuery)) {
    $arr[] = $obResult;
}
mysql_close($objConnect);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: getting this: Array ( ) 1 while printing using : echo print_r($arr);

Answer (score 0):

Try to use mysql_fetch_assoc() with while condition like

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($objQuery))
{
   $result[$row['id']]['column1'] = $row['column1']; 
   $result[$row['id']]['column2'] = $row['column2']; 
}
```

or you can directly use

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($objQuery))
{
   $result[][$row['id']] = $row; 
}
print_r($result);
```

And dont use mysql_* functions due to they are **depricated**,instead use **mysqli**_* functions or **PDO** statements

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli_* functions instead of mysql_, because they are deprecated.

Be careful with possible injection - if $strMemberID comes from outside, it might be dangerous! mysqli_escape_string helps.

```
while($obResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($objQuery)){

$arr = array();
$arr["OrderID"] = $obResult["OrderID"];
$arr["ItemDetails"] = $obResult["ItemDetails"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### use while loop to get the result

$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);

$arr = array();

while( $obResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($objQuery) ) {

$OrderID = $obResult["OrderID"];

$ItemDetails = $obResult["ItemDetails"];

array_push( $arr, array( 'OrderID' => $OrderID, 'ItemDetails' => $ItemDetails ) );

}

mysql_close($objConnect);

echo json_encode($arr);

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("mydatabase");

$strMemberID = $_POST["sMemberID"];
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE MemberID = '".$strMemberID."' ";

$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
$obResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($objQuery);

if($obResult)
{

while($row==mysql_fetch_assoc($objQuery)){
$arr = array();
$arr["OrderID"] = $obResult["OrderID"];
$arr["ItemDetails"] = $obResult["ItemDetails"];
}
}
mysql_close($objConnect);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: are you sure i need to use this line twice in my script: $obResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($objQuery);